# How to switch terminal to new child process of process launched with NSTask?

Tags: macos, terminal, spawn, pty, job-control

I made a pseudo terminal with method described here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/student-dev/2005/Mar/msg00019.html

The terminal itself worked well. Anyway the problem is terminal cannot being switched to child process. For an example, I launched `bash` with `NSTask`, and if I execute `ftp` within the `bash`, it stops automatically.

```
ftp
ftp
ftp> 
[1]+  Stopped                 ftp
bash-3.2$
```

And if I try to continue the `ftp` with `fg`, it terminates quietly. (I checked this with *Activity Monitor*)

```
fg
fg
ftp

bash-3.2$ 

fg
fg
bash: fg: current: no such job
bash-3.2$
```

I think it needs some more infrastructure (which completes pseudo terminal) to switch control to child process. What's required to do this?

Comment: what is the platform? iOs? Mac? Linux?

Comment: @DavidePiras I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally do this by creating a `pty` device. To make a program behave like "Terminal", it must be executed in an interactive terminal, and that needs pseudo-terminal device.

Unfortunately, AFAIK, `NSTask` does not support any `pty` ability, so I had to get down to BSD layer.

Here's my current implementation: https://github.com/eonil/PseudoTeletypewriter.Swift

`sudo` is working well, and I believe `ssh` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code of MFTask and PseudoTTY.app (which works on Mac OS X 10.6).

See: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask

For a pty command line tool see [here](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/8786).